# Getting ECS task definitions by tag?

Tags: aws-cli

Is it possible with the CLI to get a list of all of the ECS task definitions that match a specific tag?

Or would I need to write a script to loop through each of the task definitions to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try [GetResources](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/resourcegroupstaggingapi/get-resources.html).

Here's an example:

```bash
$ aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources \
--resource-type-filters ecs:task-definition \
--tag-filters Key=ecs:taskDefinition:createdFrom,Values=ecs-console-v2
```